# Доступ к IP-пакетам исходящего/входящего трафика android устройства

Tags: android, сеть, ip, tcp-ip

Доброго времени суток! Товарищи, для анализа объема интернет трафика использую стандартный класс `TrafficStats`. Он считает байты, пакеты...
Но как получить доступ к этим самым пакетам? Root обязателен? Нужно получить доступ хотя бы к заголовкам IP-пакетов. Есть какие-то библиотеки мб сторонние?
Грубо говоря нужен простенький сниффер без точного анализа.
Буду рад любым советам и ответам.

Comment: *Root обязателен?* -- скорее всего, это ж ещё какая конфиденциальная информация.

Comment: я подумал если есть возможность подсчитать отдельно tcp и udp пакеты значит как то ip-заголовок парсится? А мне собственно нужен хотя бы он.